# How to use a framework in NetBeans

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, frameworks, qwt

I'm trying to use a framework in NetBeans (Mac OSX).
The framework is `qwt` and it resides as qwt.framework in /Library/Frameworks.

To get a project going and using this framework I did two things in project settings:

1) Added a link option '`-framework qwt`'

2) Added include directory '`/Library/Frameworks/qwt.framework/Headers`'

This gets thing going, and programmes successfully compile and run, but I'm wondering if this is the correct way to utilise a framework in NetBeans. I guess I was hoping I could just add the framework somewhere, and not have to worry about the includes as they'd be picked up automatically.

Can anyone provide advice on a more efficient/correct way to use a framework in NetBeans?

Thanks
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit of google research, it appears there's no simpler way to utilise a framework in NetBeans than do the above steps ie. a) add a link option '`-framework xxx`' and b) add the include directory from the framework, which resides in `xxx.framework/Headers` (usually). XCode and QtCreator have options to add a framework directly, but it appears NetBeans doesn't have this option. Hope these steps are useful to someone out there wanting to use NetBeans and frameworks. (I prefer NetBeans over QtCreator to make Qt projects as I find its debugging facilities and general IDE better to use.)
Pete